# Failed to serialize the response body after upgrading from ODATA v3 to v4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a Web API server where I use ODATA (and EF 6) to return a list of Items (consumed by a WinForms client that uses a DevExpress ODataInstantFeedbackSource bound to their GridControl).

Here is the Web API controller method that returns the list of Items:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetItems(ODataQueryOptions<Item> queryOptions)
{
   var customerNumber = Request.Headers.GetValues("CustomerNumber").FirstOrDefault();
   try
   {
      queryOptions.Validate(_validationSettings);
      var query = queryOptions.ApplyTo(Context.Items) as IQueryable<Item>;
      var items = query.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new Item()
      {
         ItemNumber = i.ItemNumber,
         ItemDescription = i.ItemDescription,
         <snip>
         RebateAmount = RebateUtil.CalculateInstantRebates(i.ItemNo, customerNumber),
      }).AsQueryable();

      return Ok(items);
   }
   catch (ODataException ex)
   {
      return BadRequest(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Before I upgraded to ODATA v3, the above was working perfectly; after upgrading, I now get:

> The ObjectContent1 type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type "text/plain; charset=utf-8",  The value of type
>   "System.Linq.EnumerableQuery1[[AcmeService.Model.Item,
>   AcmeService.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]" could not be converted to a raw string.

I see the above message in the HTTP response body (Status 500).  The request URL is: http://acme.us/odata/Items/$count

Note that if I make the GetItems controller simply do a "return Ok(Context.Items)", it works fine (no error, but I need to be able to set the RebateAmount value before returning the data).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in an another context (without devexpress), but maybe this could help you.
I solved it by replacing this namespace :

```
using System.Web.Http.OData;
```

by :

```
using System.Web.OData;
```